# Invalid response from server - react-dropzone-s3-uploader

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, dropzone, react-dropzone

I'm trying to upload pictures directly to S3 with the react-dropzone-s3-uploader. I tried to follow the documentation but I'm getting this error:

```
Invalid response from server
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
 const handleFinishedUpload = info => {
    console.log('File uploaded with filename', info.filename)
    console.log('Access it on s3 at', info.fileUrl)
  }

 const uploadOptions = {
    server: 'http://localhost:3000',
    accept: "image/*",
    signingUrlQueryParams: {uploadType: 'avatar'},
  }

return (
    <>
      <DropzoneS3Uploader 
       onFinish={handleFinishedUpload} 
       s3Url={'https://mybucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/'}
       maxSize={5000 * 5000}
       upload={uploadOptions}
      />
    </>
)
```

This is what I see in the console

```
base.preprocess() 
File {preview: 'blob:http://localhost:3000/38109daa-375e-4245-b67b-499768ffc075', name: 'photo_gallery.jpg', lastModified: 1661553342327, lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 26 2022 15:35:42 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: '', …}
preview: "blob:http://localhost:3000/38109daa-375e-4245-b67b-499768ffc075"
lastModified: 1661553342327
lastModifiedDate: Fri Aug 26 2022 15:35:42 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) {}
name: "photo_gallery.jpg"
size: 972117
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
[[Prototype]]: File
```

I've been stuck with this for a long time. I first used react-dropzone and I uploaded the photos to S3, but I was having issues when displaying the initialFiles to the component so I switched to react-dropzone-s3-uploader to see if I can make it work. I'd really appreciate any help

Comment: try changing `s3Url={'https://mybucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/'}` to `s3Url={'https://mybucket.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com'}`

Comment: @monim it's still not working, i was actually trying both with and without